# Fitnesse Slim does not executing while changing the port

Tags: fitnesse

I have executed my fitnesse slim in port number 8080.after closing the browser and re-run my slim table but it shows an error, "Testing was interupted and results are incomplete. Assertions: 0 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored, 0 exceptions " like this.

Help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The SlimServer opens and listens to a server socket. It gets the port number from FitNesse via the command line. The default is 8085 and it cycles through the next 10 ports to avoid collisions. If 8085 is not convenient for you, you can set the SLIM_PORT variable to any port you like. This variable can be defined on a page by page basis with !define, or it can be specified with -DSLIM_PORT=xxxx on the java command line, or it can be an environment variable.

Is it possible an other process is running in this range? We ran into a similar problem when we put our mock service on port 8085. One out of 10 runs failed and the the exception was not very discriptive. We assume for us the problem was caused by the above, we still testing if it works. Our fitnesse port is in a completely different range btw, 9090

Answer (score 0):

When you see "Testing was interupted and results are incomplete. Assertions: 0 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored, 0 exceptions " there are a couple of things to look for:

- Do you have any code that creates an object in a static class that doesn't get cleaned up.  For example, a WebDriver BrowserDriver instance that you never called close()/quit() on.
- Is there something else left running when your test is closed and the connection is still in use and preventing a connection?
- Do you see any stack traces in the output page (the page you can get to after the test is complete that lists the Test Completed OK, or Test Completed with Errors.
- Do you see any stack traces in the command line you ran FitNesse from?

Any of these things can point you in the direction of what is causing FitNesse to fail to complete running the tests (some are causes and some are diagnostics).

Also, are you using the lastet release? Some improvements around this behavior were added to prevent a System.exit() from being called.  No guarantee this fixes it, but maybe.

Finally, when you say you closed the browser, if you are referring to the window you ran the test from, then you need to understand that FitNesse has no idea that the browser window that launched a test is still there or not. It keeps running the test and doesn't care that there isn't a client waiting for the result.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should have a look at Xebium. I am not affiliated at all with Xebia but I use it daily for testing functionality within browsers and works very well

also could you clarify the question a little bit more? What does the test case look like? How is your setup etc

thanks

Comment: Unless you know for sure that this person is using web testing, I'm not sure recommending Xebium is very helpful.  I would have focused on your question as a comment instead.